# How to automate a large number of txt files to be imported from Perl to a SQL Server using DBI?

Tags: sql-server, perl, bulkinsert, dbi

I have attempted to transfer one txt file into a SQL Server from Perl, but I now need to create a DB in SQL that combines hundreds of txt files. Is there an automated way of doing this to save manually transferring all the txt files? I will insert my attempt of coding one txt file. I believe I need to use Bulk Insert to achieve this but I am unsure what code to use. Any advice on the problem would be really appreciated, and if there is anymore code you wish to see or a specific thing I forgot to mention then please comment and I will edit. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use DBI;
use Carp;

    # Connect to the data source and get a handle for that connection.
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:RegressionDBS') ||
    confess "Connection Failed: $DBI::errstr";

    # This query generates a result set with one record in it.
my $sql = "SELECT 1 AS test_col";
my $tablename = "RegressionTable";

open(FH, "newregression.txt") || die "cant open file";
my $Sqlh = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO RegressionTable (Ticker, TradeDate, HighPrice, LowPrice, TradePrice, TotalVolume, TotalValue) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);") || confess $DBI::errstr;
while (my $line = <FH> )
{
$line =~/^(.*)(..)(..)$/;
my ($curTicker, $wTradeDate, $wHighPrice, $wLowPrice, $wTradePrice, $wTotalVolume, $wTotalValue);
    $curTicker=$1
    #$wTradeDate=
    $wHighPrice=$2;
    $wLowPrice=$1;
    #$wTradePrice=$1;
    #$wTotalVolume=$1;
    #$wTotalValue=$4;

$Sqlh->execute($curTicker, $wTradeDate, $wHighPrice, $wLowPrice, $wTradePrice, $wTotalVolume, $wTotalValue) || confess $DBI::errstr; 
}

$Sqlh->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you run

```
INSERT INTO RegressionTable (
  Ticker, TradeDate, HighPrice, LowPrice, TradePrice, TotalVolume, TotalValue
) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

for every line in `newregression.txt`, and now you want to do it for multiple files. Why not wrap your code above in a subroutine, say `insert_file()`, then call it per file in a loop...

```
my @files = qw(red.txt green.txt blue.txt);
for my $file (@files) {
  insert_file($file);
}
```

Or if the target table varies per file, define a hash:

```
my %files = (
  'red.txt'  => 'RedTable', 
  'blue.txt' => 'BlueTable'
);
while ( my ($file, $table) = each %files ) {
  insert_file($file, $table);
};
```

Not sure how you'd use [Bulk Insert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) given the field separator in your data file seems to be indeterminate (i.e. the regex `/(.*)(..)(..)/` defines field boundaries). You may need to use the `FORMATFILE` option. Also, if you generate a `BULK INSERT` statement using DBI, be aware that the user your SQL Server runs as must be able to read your data files over the filesystem (networked, local or otherwise).

Comment: Does your suggestion not then require each txt file name to be input? For I need to insert 300+ file names in that case? I was hoping to get the fastest way possible to do this? Also I dont need to use the field separator anymore so thats no longer an issue. It will also be networked locally. Thanks

Comment: You needn't name each input file. You can use a glob: `my @files = glob '*.txt';` then loop thru each file in @files as above.